# "Siempre" Neruda

Tags: poesía

¿Qué significa *antes de mí* en el poema de Neruda? ¿Es algo propiamente chileno?¹

> ### **Siempre**
>
> Antes de mí
>   no tengo celos.
>
> Ven con un hombre
>   a la espalda,
>   ven con cien hombres en tu cabellera,
>   ven con mil hombres entre tu pecho y tus pies,
>   ven como un río
>   lleno de ahogados
>   que encuentra el mar furioso,
>   la espuma eterna, el tiempo.
>
> Tráelos todos
>   adonde yo te espero:
>   siempre estaremos solos,
>   siempre estaremos tú y yo
>   solos sobre la tierra
>   para comenzar la vida.
>
> *Pablo Neruda.*

---

[1] Siempre creía haber entendido el *antes* como un adverbio verdaderamente temporal pero curiosamente leí la traducción al inglés donde aparece ***facing*** you, I'm not jealous. No digo que no sean consistentes los textos, sólo pregunto sobre la exactitud del carácter temporal de *antes*.

Answer (score 5):

"Facing You" sería `ante mí`, que como dices no es lo mismo que `antes de mí`. La traducción de este último sería "before me", como en:

> Antes de mí, había una mujer en este puesto  <sub>Before me, there was a woman in this position</sub>

En [esta versión anotada del poema en inglés](http://genius.com/Pablo-neruda-always-annotated/) la traducción es

> I am not jealous of what came **before me**.

(que es por cierto la que siempre me ha aparecido al hacer una búsqueda en google de "always pablo neruda". Quizá la versión que tú encontraste es la rara excepción con una traducción más "*amateur*", que confunde "antes" y "ante")

Si haces click en los primeros versos aparece una especie de [explicación o anotaciones](http://genius.com/2927576/Pablo-neruda-always/I-am-not-jealous-of-what-came-before-me-come-with-a-man-on-your-shoulders-come-with-a-hundred-men-in-your-hair-come-with-a-thousand-men-between-your-breasts-and-your-feet-come-like-a-river-full-of-drowned-men-which-flows-down-to-the-wild-sea-to-the-eternal-surf-to-time-bring-them-all-to-where-i-am-waiting-for-you) que confirma que

> Neruda le explica a su "amor" que a él, no le importa las cosas que ella haya hecho *antes de que él estuviera con ella*, él no puede estar celoso de algo que sucedió *antes de que él estuviera con ella*.

Como dices ese `antes` es un adverbio de caracter temporal. Mi suposición, como dije antes, es que quien hizo esa traducción que encontraste con "facing you" confundió "antes de mí" y "ante (de) mí".

Answer (score 3):

Me parece que esa traducción al inglés es incorrecta. Leyendo el resto del poema entiendo que está diciendo que no está celoso de los hombres que estuvieron con ella antes que él. Esos son los hombres que ella lleva en la espalda, cabellera, etc.

No creo que sea una expresión chilena, simplemente en poesía se juega con el lenguaje.

[Aquí](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/761560-i-am-not-jealous-of-what-came-before-me-come) hay otra traducción consistente con lo que digo:

```
I am not jealous
of what came before me.

Come with a man
on your shoulders,
come with a hundred men in your hair,
come with a thousand men between your breasts and your feet,
come like a river
full of drowned men
which flows down to the wild sea,
to the eternal surf, to Time!

Bring them all
to where I am waiting for you;
we shall always be alone,
we shall always be you and I
alone on earth,
to start our life!
```

Answer (score 1):

No es un chilenismo ni lenguaje poético. Simplemente significa que no me importa con cuántos otros hombres estuviste antes de conocerme a mí, o de estar conmigo.

*Estoy esperando que me atienda el doctor. **Antes de mí** hay dos personas.*

**Antes de** se refiere a una **posición** en una línea o una pila. Si bien se origina en el paso del tiempo, se puede aplicar a cualquier otro ámbito que metafóricamente se asimile a un tránsito con un delante y un atrás.

Se puede estar antes en orden alfabético. Un elemento está antes que otro en la tabla periódica. El tres está antes que el cuatro. Temuco está antes que Valdivia según se viaja de norte a sur.

Comment: *Antes de mí no tengo celos* es lenguaje poético. No es una oración que tenga sentido en lenguaje corriente.